# getting total count of employee with total number of transaction

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a employee table with

```
employeeid, country, state, and city
```

then i have transaction table with

```
transaction_id, employeeid, transaction-details
```

So I need

```
country state city total(no_of_employee), count(transactions), count(no_of_employee_done_transaction)
```

I've tried and able to get

```
country state city count(transactions), count(no_of_employee_done_transaction)
```

by using this query:

```
 select em.Country, em.state, em.city , count(transaction_id) as "count(transaction)" , count(distinct(employeeid)) as "count(number of employee done transaction)" 
    from transaction tr
    right outer join employee em on tr.employeeid = em.employeeid
    where to_char(tran_date,'Mon-YYYY')='Jun-2014'
    group by em.country,em.state, em.city;
```

if i put `count(employee_id)` in select list then it always comes equal to `count(transaction_id)`
 what to modify to achieve `count(employee_id)` in above query.

Comment: Please provide sample table data & desired result.

Comment: i.e. you want two different counts from the transaction table per city? I don't think you can do that in a single query without subqueries or CTEs or similar.

Comment: Have you tried `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN transaction_id IS NOT NULL THEN employeeid) AS "count(no_of_employee_done_transaction)"`

Comment: yes @Rup, you're right. please suggest some related query

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at one place you want total count of employees from employees table and in the second place, you want employees who have done transaction from transactions table. Try :

```
 select em.Country, 
        em.state, 
        em.city , 
        count(distinct em.employeeid), 
        count(transaction_id) as "count(transaction)" , 
        count(distinct tr.employeeid) as "count(number of employee done transaction)" 
    from transaction tr
    right outer join employee em on tr.employeeid = em.employeeid
    where to_char(tran_date,'Mon-YYYY')='Jun-2014'
    group by em.country,em.state, em.city;
```

Comment: again count(distinct em.employeeid) is equal to count(distinct tr.employeeid)

Comment: It means, for Jun-2014, every employee has done atleast one transaction. You can check from individual tables, once from transaction for month Jun-2014 and again taking the count from employee table.

Comment: sorry count(distinct em.employeeid) is coming equal to count(transaction_id) as "count(transaction)"

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQL Subquery](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm).

```
select a.employeeid,a.country,a.state,a.city,
(select count(*) from employees) as count_employees,
(select count(*) from transactions) as count_transactions,
(select count(*) from employees where employee_id=a.employee_id) as no_of_employee_transactions
   from transactions a
where to_char(a.tran_date,'Mon-YYYY')='Jun-2014' 
group by a.employeeid,a.country,a.state,a.city;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear on your requirement. Please see if this is what you want.

```
select em.Country, em.state, em.city , count(transaction_id) as "count(transaction)" , count(distinct(employeeid)) as "count(number of employee done transaction)",
(select count(distinct(employeeid)) as total(no_of_employee) 
    from employee c 
    where em.Country = c.Country
          em.state   = c.state
          em.city    = c.city)
    from transaction tr
    right outer join employee em on tr.employeeid = em.employeeid
    where to_char(tran_date,'Mon-YYYY')='Jun-2014'
    group by em.country,em.state, em.city;
```

Comment: Yes the Distinct is redundant. Thanks for pointing out @DamienJoe.